# Is the bitonic sort algorithm stable?

Tags: sorting, sorting-network, stable

I was wondering, is the bitonic sort algorithm stable? I searched the [original paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808726), wikipedia and some tutorials, could not find it.

It seems to me that it should be, as it is composed of merge / sort steps, however was unable to find answer anywhere.

The reason why I'm asking - I was comparing [this particular implementation of bitonic sort](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/bitonic/oddn.htm) to the sort implemented in the C++ standard library, for array length 9 it requires 28 comparison / swap operations, while the standard library sort (which is unstable) requires 25. The three extra cswaps do not seem enough to make the sort stable.

Comment: [Bitonic sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) is a sorting network.  Can a sorting network be _not_ stable?  How do you define for a sorting network to be stable?

Comment: By the way, I cannot understand the motivation you stated in the last paragraph.  You compared the number of comparisons needed for n=9 between bitonic sort and some unstable sort, and you found that bitonic sort required more comparisons.  How is this related to whether bitonic sort is stable or not?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto instinctively, stability seems like something you need to "pay for". so why is stable sort more expensive than unstable one? Sorting network can be unstable, I have come over a peculiar bubble sort implementation (I'm a teacher, I get to see a lots of strange stuff that my students write), which was unstable and thanks to the fixed number of steps it took, it could be implemented as a sorting network. Not practical, but very possible.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I also thought that sorting networks would be automatically stable (as a corollary of the 0-1 principle), but it seems that this is not the case. See http://hoytech.github.io/sorting-networks/ pages 27–28.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela: Thanks for the link!  I stand corrected.

Comment: @theswine: In `The Art of Computer Programming Vol. 3 Sorting and Searching` Knuth explains that we pay for the uniformity of sorting networks with an increased number of comparisons compared to the optimum.

Comment: Stating the obvious, you can make Bitonic sort stable by appending the port numbers to the sort keys (or array indices in the c++ case.)  Suppose you have items A and B with equal sort keys 50 at indices 7 and 11.   5007 and 5011 will sort A and B in the correct order of A and B (vs B then A)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, bitonic sort is not stable.

For this post I will denote numbers as 2;0 where only the part before the `;` is used for comparison and the part behind `;` to mark the initial position.
Comparison-exchanges are denoted by arrows where the head points at the desired location of the greater value.

As written in the [link](http://hoytech.github.io/sorting-networks/) that [@JukkaSuomela posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27104/is-the-bitonic-sort-algorithm-stable#comment64830_27104) a stable sorting network needs to avoid swaps of equal values.

When swapping equal values, the bitonic sorter for two values is already unstable:

```
0;0 ----- 0;1
      |
      v
0;1 ----- 0;0
```

Of course, this can be fixed when we don't swap equal values:

```
0;0 ----- 0;0
      |
      v
0;1 ----- 0;1
```

However, it could happen that the order of two equal elements is swapped without them being compared to each other.

This is exactly the case in this example of a bitonic sorter for 4 values:

```
1;0 ------ 1;0 ------ 0;2 ------ 0;2
      ^          |          |
      |          |          v
1;1 ------ 1;1 --|--- 1;1 ------ 1;1
                 ||
                 v|
0;2 ------ 0;2 ---|-- 1;0 ------ 1;0
      |           |         |
      v           v         v
2;3 ------ 2;3 ------ 2;3 ------ 2;3
```

Although we were careful not to swap elements that compared equal (upper left comparison), the merging pass swapped the order of 1;1 and 1;0 which cannot be corrected later on.

This counterexample proves that bitonic sort cannot be stable.

Comment: I am afraid the second stage is wrong since a merger network reverses its second input to make the whole concatenated input bitonic. Therefore, the second stage should compare between element 1 and element 4, and element 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

It could become stable, but in an inefficient way.

See [Is there any efficient Network stable sort (not bubble sort)?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/is-there-any-efficient-network-stable-sort-not-bubble-sort) which demonstrates it